# How to correctly cast void pointer to blob to a struct-pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

**short:**

what I receive:

```
void* -> blob |version(int)|timestamp(long)|number(unsigned)|data(char[x])|
```

what I want:

cast it into a pointer of type `Data*`

**explicit:**

I am receiving a BLOB via network and want to cast it into the following structure (or a similar one):

```
struct Data
{
    struct Header
    {
        int version;
        long timestamp;
        unsigned number;
    }__attribute__((packed)) header
    unsigned char* data;
}
```

where Data.data is an array of unsigned chars of variable length (a JPEG image).
This array is generated by the turbo-JPEG library and I set the pointer `Data.data = generated_image`(of type unsigned char[])

The problem is on the receiver side, where I try to cast a void pointer to the `blob` into a pointer to `struct Data`. No problem for the Header, but `Data->data` seems to be null/out of bounds, instead of being a char array.

I **cannot** use a constant length, as I do **not** know the length of the `data`!

Comment: Are you just sending the `struct`? If so, you will be sending the pointer, which on the receiving side will point nowhere.

Comment: @BoBTFish "the data is definetly being sent via network, as I am watching the network"

Comment: There is a syntax error in the example, the inner `struct Header` is declared but never actually used, it should be e.g. `struct Header {...} header;` to create a member of `struct Data` of that type.

Comment: @unwind this is not my actual code, just for visualisation of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, yes, my comment was too brief. What I mean is that the `Data` instance contains a pointer to the buffer, which actually lives elsewhere. When you pick up the `Data` instance at the other end, it's pointer has the same underlying value, but on this side, that address does *not* contain the buffer. You will need to change that pointer to point to the new location of the buffer.

Comment: @Theolodis thank you so much for making us invest our valuable time not only on finding a solution to your problem, but on also having to find the problem first. If you can't bother to describe your problem properly, how can you expect us to find a proper solution?

Comment: @Theolodis Perhaps you don't realise that by not including your real code, your question is equivalent to: "Here's some code: `int main(){ std::cout << "Hello world\n"; }`. Why does my Doom clone crash?"

Comment: It's never a good idea to try use structs directly on network data streams. You can have issues with packing, data type sizes, and byte ordering.  You have to serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are sending it using something like:

```
Data d;
// fill in d
send(SOME_SOCKET, static_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(d), ...);
```

That will send your `Data` structure, but will include the value of the `data` pointer, not what it is pointing to.

It would probably be better for you to store the data as below and send it as header and body:

```
struct Data
{
    struct Header
    {
        int version;
        long timestamp;
        unsigned number;

        std::size_t size;
    }
    //unsigned char* data;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
};
```

So that you also have the size of data and to serialize it to the socket seperately:

```
d.header.size = d.data.size();
send(SOME_SOCKET, &d.header, sizeof(d.header), ...);
send(SOME_SOCKET, &d.data[0], d.data.size(), ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 unsigned char* data;
```

Sending `data` to another process just sends an address from current process's memory space and it's not useful for another process (exclude shared memory). You should serialize it to sequence of bytes before sending.

A simple workaround is:

```
struct Data
{
    struct Header
    {
        int version;
        long timestamp;
        unsigned number;
    }
    unsigned char data[FIXED_SIZE];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the time, but I can't use a fixed length, as the image is of variable, undefined length.